# Ubuntu on Capacitive and active touchscreen laptops

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen, compatibility, stylus

I'm thinking of getting a Lenovo yoga 510 or 520 and install Ubuntu on it, as currently i'm a ubuntu user. Both laptops are good on hardware, the main difference being that the 520 comes with an active stylus and the 510 doesn't (apparently could work with a capacitive one).

I'd like to know experiences from other users with these models or similar. How good would current versions of Ubuntu run on this ones? How well does a stylus work with ubuntu (precision, palm rejection, which softwares are good for this)?

If anyone knows the advantages of an active, wacom-like touchscreen vs a normal one like the one on the 510 it would be helpfull too!

Answer (score 0):

The French Community of Ubuntu Users has a long list of Lenovo laptops (including Yoga series) tested with different versions of Ubuntu that includes test results.

[List of Lenovo Laptops](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.ubuntu-fr.org%2Fliste_portables_lenovo&edit-text=&act=url) (Through Google Translate)